# MySQL -- Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table, prepare

I've searched through the dozens of questions with near identical title to this post, but I have yet to find answer to my specific problem.  I'm trying to prepare a statement, but I get this error every time.  I'm thinking there must me some sort of error on my sql syntax, but for the life of me I cannot find it.

```
$title = "this_is_my_table_title";    

//import the database login credential variables
require("localhost_credentials.php");

$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$querystr  = "CREATE TABLE ? (";
$querystr .= "id int(11) not null auto_increment,";
$querystr .= "section varchar(255) not null,";
$querystr .= "raw_content LONGTEXT not null,";
$querystr .= "formatted_content LONGTEXT not null,";
$querystr .= "primary key (id)";
$querystr .= ");";


$statement = $conn->prepare($querystr);  <--- error here
$statement->bind_param("s", $title);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
```

Comment: When `prepare` returns `false`, do `echo $conn->error` to see the SQL error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a placeholder for a table name, it can only be used in place of expressions. So `CREATE TABLE ?` is not valid. Use:

```
$querystr  = "CREATE TABLE `$title` (";
```

after validating that `$title` is an acceptable table name.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Didn't know that, I thought I could use placeholders anywhere.  Thanks!  That fixed it.

Comment: That's a common misunderstanding.